# How to solve fourth degree equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

How do I solve?

$\frac{4}{x^2}=5-x^2$

My textbook just solve it like

$(x^2 −4)(x^2 −1)=0$

but do not explain how to to do it

Comment: **Hint:** Multiply both sides by $x^2$, simplify and factor.

Comment: Yeah but how do I factor something like that?

Answer (score 2):

multplying by $x^2$ we obtain:
$$x^4-5x^2+4=0$$ Setting $t=x^2$
we get;
$$t^2-5t+4=0$$ this is a quadratic equation to solve

Answer (score 1):

As the hint given by @Moo says

$$4=5x^2-x^4 \Rightarrow x^4-5x^2+4=0,$$

then let $u=x^2$ so

$$u^2-5u+4=0.$$

Can you finish from here?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{4}{x^2} &= 5-x^2 \\
\dfrac{4}{x^2} - 5+x^2 &=0\\
\dfrac{4}{x^2} - \dfrac{5}{1} + \dfrac{x^2}{1} &=0\\ 
\dfrac{4-5x^2+x^4}{x^2}  &=0\\ 
\dfrac{4-4x^2-x^2+x^4}{x^2}  &=0\\ 
\dfrac{4(1-x^2)-x^2(1-x^2)}{x^2}  &=0\\ 
\dfrac{(4-x^2)(1-x^2)}{x^2}  &=0
\end{align}
for $x^2\neq0$ we have $(4-x^2)(1-x^2)=0$ or $(x^2-4)(x^2-1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we get $$4=5x^2-x^4$$ that is, we get $$x^4-5x^2+4=0$$ then  we get (by using factoring, it is quadratic in form) $$(x^2-4)(x^2-1)=0.$$